# UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl not showing, other system icon does

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am using a custom-made toolbar (`UIToolBar`), which shall display some items/buttons. One of them, however, *does not* show up. It is there, I can click it, it responds and fires the selector, but it is invisible.

This is how I build the toolbar:

```
spacer=    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
menuItem=  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[JASidePanelController defaultImage] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:(TabController*)self.parentViewController action:@selector(handleShowMenu)] autorelease];
addItem=   [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:[Storage currentStorage] action:@selector(showAddDialog)] autorelease];
titleItem= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[self pageTitle] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];

UIBarButtonItem* mapItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(toggleMapType)] autorelease];

NSArray* items= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuItem, spacer, titleItem, spacer, mapItem, addItem, nil];

toolbar= [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, TOOLBARHEIGHT)] autorelease];

[toolbar setItems:items];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

This will not display:

```
UIBarButtonItem* mapItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:@selector(toggleMapType)] autorelease];
```

[image: Doesnt work]

But replacing this line with:

```
UIBarButtonItem* mapItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(toggleMapType)] autorelease];
```

will make the item show.

[image: Does work]

Anyone knows **why**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`UIBarButtonSystemItem` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem),

> This bar button image can be used only for bar button items placed on toolbars.

You're trying to place it on a navigation bar, which isn't allowed.

It looks like this:

[image: Page curl]

That's not quite in line with iOS 7+ design guidelines, so that may also be an issue, but the docs don't say anything about deprecation, so it shouldn't be.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using an `UIToolBar`, **not** a navigation bar.

Comment: @user826955 I see: that's an odd way of doing it, as `UIToolBar`s [should be at the bottom of the screen on iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html). Regardless, I can't see a page curl looking too great with your current setup; it doesn't look like it has been updated to follow the new design guidelines.

Comment: I am having an `UITabBar` on the bottom already (using `UITabBarController`), which navigates the app. The `UIToolBar` on the top is not meant to provide navigation functionality. Apart from my original question, which is still unanswered, what should I do about the top-placed toolbar then?

Comment: @user826955 I'd choose another system icon or design one yourself; I just  tried adding the page curl icon to a toolbar in an example project, and it was still invisible, with the warning "Page Curl bar button system item identifier in iPad documents," which a cursory Google search didn't turn up anything for. It may be deprecated, as it doesn't appear on the [list of standard buttons for bars](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html), but Apple doesn't say that officially anywhere.